# remove background from vector image in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I opened a `png` image in Inkscape and did **Path** -> **Trace Bitmap** to vectorize it, but on preview my image was without blue color. How do I remove that blue background to get only black edge.

[image]

The **Trace Bitmap** settings are like this:
[image]

Comment: Is remove background checked?

Comment: yes, you can see it on screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Set number of scan as 2. It will reduce a group of paths.

[image]